# jenkins plugin to fail build based on console output

Tags: plugins, build, jenkins

Is there a plugin to fail a build if a pattern occurs on the console output?

For example:

```
Build Action - success
Build Action - success
Build Action - error_pattern
Build Action - success
```

Let's assume that the Jenkins build process does not fail the build on error_pattern, I need to have an external fail trigger of some sort.

### EDIT

Looking for a solution to fail the build during, not a post build task.

Answer (score 9):

You should try the [Post Build Task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin.
You can search for a pattern and then launch a script.

edit: 
There is also [Text finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin), looks better for your problem

Comment: Unfortunately both plugins run after the build is done and what I was looking for is something to fail the build during the build (the build should run and fail after 20min and not 6h for example)

Comment: Oh ok ... (maybe you should precise this in your question :) )

Comment: found anything afterwards? I'm having similar situation that some build steps fail and print out certain string means it's failed, but we can't restart the build until the pre-defined timeout time elapsed

Answer (score 1):

As an ugly workaround I do the following: in the build script redirect all the output to some resulting .log file, then you can grep through this file in the background the way you like (personally I do the freezing check additionally - calculate the checksum and compare with previous, if the same - start counting for timeout until threshold), etc...

Disadvantage is the output goes to some file instead of Jenkins console, but I guess you can do both using `tee` (I don't care, because my goal is to archive the log anyways and send it via email, - so I just `gzip` my resulting .log file and attach it as an artifact to the build record + to the email).

Advantage is you have full control on what happens in the build output and can interrupt the build using your own return code / message.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing any code examples you could provide

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45373956/2927684) as the basis of a pipeline script. In the "Build" stage I have two parallel sub-stages - one of them is doing the actual build and outputting to a log, whilst the other sub-stage is grepping the same log. I've negated the exit code (`! grep`) so that it'll error when the "ERROR:" string is found. Thanks to the `failFast` setting, this will cause the whole "Build" stage to fail as soon as the string is found. There's an extra `grep` at the end of the first sub-stage, in case an error was produced right at the end.

I'm tracking the build status with a variable (`BUILD_COMPLETE`).

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    environment {
        BUILD_COMPLETE = false
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            failFast true
            parallel {
                stage('Building') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'echo foo | tee output.log'
                        sleep 5
                        sh 'echo bar | tee -a output.log'
                        sleep 5
                        sh 'echo ERROR: baz | tee -a output.log'
                        sleep 5
                        sh 'echo qux | tee -a output.log'
                        sleep 5

                        sh '! grep "^ERROR:" output.log'

                        script {
                            BUILD_COMPLETE = true
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Monitoring the logs') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            while (BUILD_COMPLETE != true) {
                                sh '! grep "^ERROR:" output.log'
                                sleep 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```